# Selenium IDE - where can I find the source js code for assertTextPresent?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have downloaded the SeleniumIDE.xpi but can't seem to locate the code for assertTextPresent. I am assuming it is a javascript. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Cant got ur question as per my understanding there are 2 commands available for verification of Text Present

1. verify text present
2. assert text present

and value should be given in this way 
Command: Verifytextpresnt
Target:  {Text that has been to be verified}
Value:    {Blank}